# Expected out is not coming in Django python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I am new to python! I was trying to scrap menu structure of any website!

the out is coming fine when I tried in VScode!

here is the code

```
for i in menu_items('https://natureshair.com.au/'):
   print(json.dumps(i, indent=6))
```

And this is the output, Script can scrap all the menu

[image: menu]

Now I am trying to collect this website and display results using Django! the strange thing is if I use the same website the output is empty!

here is the code :

```
def product(request):
    finaldata=request.GET["title"]
    finaldata1=request.GET["title1"]
    finaldata2=request.GET["title2"]
    results = list(
        item
        #for link in ('https://natureshair.com.au/', 'https://www.trafficradius.com.au/')
        for link in (finaldata,finaldata1,finaldata2)
        for item in menu_items(link))
    return JsonResponse({'results': results})
```

Output:
[image: empty output]

```
def to_dict(r):
   if all(isinstance(i, dict) for i in r):
      return {a:b for i in r for a, b in i.items()}
   if all(isinstance(i, list) for i in r):
      return [i for b in r for i in b]
   return r

def get_menu(page_name):
   if page_name.name == 'li':
      #collect all li values, create a dictionary if li has a ul child
      li_text = []
      for i in page_name.contents:
         if isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString) or i.select_one('ul') is None:
           if (t:=i.get_text(strip=True)): #default li text
              li_text.append(t)
         else: #li contains a ul, build a dict with li's text as key
            if li_text:
               li_text.append({li_text.pop():to_dict([*get_menu(i)])})
               
            else:
               yield to_dict([*get_menu(i)])
      yield from li_text
      return
   all_text = []
   for i in page_name.contents:
      if getattr(i, 'name', None) == 'ul':
         r = [*get_menu(i)] #get ul's li values
         e, flag = i, False
         while (e:=e.previous_sibling) is not None: #check if ul has descriptive text
           if (isinstance(e, bs4.element.NavigableString) or e.select_one('ul') is None) and e.get_text(strip=True):
              yield {e.get_text(strip=True):to_dict(r)} #yield back dictionary if text exists
              flag = True
              break
         if not flag: yield to_dict(r)
      elif not isinstance(i, bs4.element.NavigableString):
         yield from get_menu(i) #recursively traverse element

def menu_items(link):
   page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'html.parser')
   for nav in page.select('nav'): #find all `nav` elements from which to anchor search
      yield to_dict([*get_menu(nav)])
```

Note: it not working for a few websites like 'https://natureshair.com.au/' and this is working fine in VS code!

Not sure where I am wrong

here is the link to my project [My projrct](http://43.204.136.240:8080/menuurl)

Comment: Can you provide `menu_items` functionality because your code looks okay.

Comment: i have updated my question with the required code

Comment: I've tested this site `natureshair.com.au` they've set bot protection cloudflare site verification for bot & it returns only this content `natureshair.com.au

Verifying you are human. This may take a few seconds.

O

natureshair.com.au needs to review the security of your connection before
proceeding.

Ray ID: esbeceds8t742beb

Performance & security by Cloudflare` bacause of this you're not able to extract data.

Comment: Also, one more doubt, how come the output is coming in VS code? for the same website (natureshair.com.au)

Comment: Because they've set [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy so If you try to request data from different domain other than `natureshair.com.au` it will block your requests. When you request from your VS it's not in browser environment it's http client it does not involve browser it communicate server-to-server.

Comment: okay got it ! Thanks! No solution for this?